# Determine if an SSD supports SATA 6Gb/s

Tags: windows, ssd, sata, speed

I had a dell computer with an SSD and on the SSD itself it said 3Gbps. They sent me a replacement laptop and the ssd is thinner (still 2.5 inch, but it's thinner) but I'm trying to see if it's 6gbps because I'm trying to figure out which one to keep. I used "speccy" but it didn't give me speeds. Any ideas?

Comment: 'thinner' vs 'thicker' probably refers to the 9mm thickness that older drives use, and the newer 7mm drives

Comment: Thanks for that info. Does that usually mean anything else? Like better lifetime or anything?

Comment: It means its thinner. Thats about it. The thinner drives are a result of the push towards 'ultrabooks' and other such devices. I seem to recall *even* thinner drives from WD... 5mm maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [CrystalDiskInfo](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html).  If the SSD is running at 6Gb/s (6 gigabits per second, or 600 megabytes per second theoretical maximum speed), the **Transfer Mode** field will read **SATA/600**.

Your SSD, as well as the motherboard in your computer, must both support SATA 6Gb/s in order for the SSD to operate in the SATA/600 transfer mode.  If either one or both support only SATA 3Gb/s, this field will read **SATA/300**.

Comment: I ran CrystalDiskInfo on my old laptop and it said that the health of the drive was 82%. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Update: It says SATA/600. Awesome. Thank you Dell!

Comment: @EGHDK: regarding 82%: This is intended to give a visual indication of the remaining lifespan of the drive.  This value is more likely to be valid for SSDs, but may also be calculated from HDD SMART parameters as well.  Related: [Is there a way to monitor an SSD state and predict its failure in case of active read-write usage?](http://superuser.com/questions/432668/is-there-a-way-to-monitor-an-ssd-state-and-predict-its-failure-in-case-of-active)