# Software to check if a SATA III drive is connected to SATA III port?

Tags: ssd, sata, diagnostic

I had an OCZ Vertex 256 GB drive installed in my PC at work, and the motherboard has SATA III ports.

How do I check the drive is connected to a SATA III port and not a SATA II port without opening the case? (AS SSD benchmarks gives me around 250 MB/s sequential read speed when it should be around 500 with this drive)

Here's what HW INFO gives me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/476831/determine-if-an-ssd-supports-sata-6gb-s

Answer (score 1):

You can grab a free app called HD Tune that tells you on it's info tab what Standard it's using.  Ironically I think you just made me realize why mines not as fast as I thought it should be ^__^

Comment: Hm, is it the interface the drive supports or it is currently connected to on the info tab?

Comment: That's strange, I have both versions of HD Tune installed, one is the normal free version and one is hd tune pro.  Hd tune pro is the only one reporting my sata3 plugged in and working on the correct drive, the free version is only stating that both of my internal drives are plugged into sata 2 so I'm betting that yours isn't showing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Yeah, it was showing sata III when the drive was actually connected to a sata II port.

Answer (score 0):

wow! both of your hard disks are running on **SATA3** speed (**6 gb/s**) that means your mobo driver and ports works fine on sata III speed.
in HWiNFO in both pages you can see your hard disks running on sata III speed.
Use HD Tune to exact measure your speed but remember to always upgrade your motherboard BIOS and ssd firmware.
you can find your ssd firmware from below link:

[OCZ Support](http://www.ocztechnology.com/ssd_tools/)

Comment: They actually were on sata II ports, I ended up opening the case, checking it visually and switching the cables to SATA III ports. I guess what HW Info shows is what the drive is capable of supporting, not the type of the interface its connected to.

Comment: wow thanks for that, and I recommend you using Aida64 instead of using HWiNFO . but always keep ssd hard disk firmware up to date.

Answer (score 0):

click the following icon under Drives, and you will see the hardisk speed and mobo speed :
(1) OCZ-VERTEX4 ----- 6GB/s @ 3GB/s ...meaning speed downgraded to 3GB/s due to mobo limitation
(2) WDxxxx     ------ 3GB/s @ 3GB/s ...meaning speed fully maximised